# How to get fb app scoped id from global id and access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, userid

I have created test users in FB test accounts page. I can see user global ids there and can get user related access tokens for each user in format v2.10 and v2.11 of the app.

How to get user application scoped id based on this 2 parameters?

I have browsed last 5 hours on internet and read FB docs, but nothing found like that.

Thanks

Comment: you should never get global ids, you only get app scoped ids after authorizing users with your app.

Comment: I dont need global id,  I already have it under specific app under test users. Also I have token for this user. But fb doesnt show app specific ids so I can see in our DB which use r is which to match to test users in fb app page.

Comment: in one app, one user will always get the same id for identification/matching.

Comment: @theguy any progress about issue? I have old users' global id and i need to match to app scoped id